# I am trying to make a script for damage but it comes up with an error saying the namespace "Player" isn't recognized

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my code:

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Obstacle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int damage = 1;
    public float speed;
    private void Update() 
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player")) {
            other.GetComponent <Player> ().health -= damage;
            Debug.Log(other.GetComponent<Player>().health);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    } 
}
```

The lines

```
other.GetComponent <Player> ().health -= damage;
Debug.Log(other.GetComponent<Player>().health);
```

are what cause the error.
This is the error that comes up:
Assets\Scripts\Obstacle.cs(17,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Player' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Any help would be greatly appreciated and I apologise if this is a stupid question, I am very new to c# and Unity

Comment: Please do not add unrelated tags to your question. This isn't related to the Visual Studio application or to Unityscript (the now-deprecated programming language that Unity originally preferred before switching to C#).

Comment: Do you have a **Player.cs** script?

Comment: no... I just have an object named player. Should I change the player to my player script?

Edit: just tried it, thankyou @Iggy!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Unity, but I can say that in C#. if you have a player class, you probably have to have a 'using' statement for the namespace that it's in. So if Player is in Game.GameObjects, you'd have to have 'using Game.GameObjects;' at the top of this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have (or create) Player.cs script (class) in your project.
It can be created in Project tab with a right mouse button: Create/C# Script.

It can look like this to avoid your exception (error):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health = 5;
}
```

Also potentially you want to kill (destroy) object if Life is going bellow or equal 0. In this case your script can look like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Obstacle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int damage = 1;
    public float speed = 1;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Player player = other.GetComponent<Player>();

            //If "other" Game Object has Player component.
            if (player)
            { 
                player.health -= damage;
                Debug.Log(player.health);

                if(player.health <= 0)
                {
                    Destroy(gameObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers!